# Public data sets for Cranfield experiment

Tags: information-retrieval

I am trying to evaluate an information retrieval approach. Thus, I need data suitable for a [Cranfield experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cranfield_Experiments):

1. Documents (D)
2. Queries (Q)
3. Relevance(Q, D)

Unfortunately I haven't found anything that is freely available...

Comment: You may find partial or variant of "Cranfield" collection (225 queries, 1398 documents and 1837 relevance judgements) on the website of University of Glasogow among other IR collections: 
http://ir.dcs.gla.ac.uk/resources/test_collections/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**DataSets:**

Cranfield had released a collection of about 3000 abstracts and a set of queries with relevance judgements. However, working with this collection is not advisable because it is very small.

For moderate sized collections, you can use the TREC ad hoc search data which comes in 5 volumes. Volumes 4 and 5 are typically used. These documents (about half a million) correspond to the TREC Robust query set (TREC 6/7/8 and Robust tracks) comprising of 250 queries in total.

INEX ad hoc search task data comprises of a collection of XML documents (a collection of 27G of Wikipedia dump). The relevance judgements include relevant paragraphs marked within the whole articles. The task is to retrieve these passages.

For non-English documents, you can use the CLEF data (European languages) or the FIRE data (South Asian languages).

For larger collections you can use the ClueWeb (TREC web search track). The size is 25Tb.

Alternatively, you can also use domain specific test collections, such as the Tweets corpus (TREC microblog search track), legal documents (TREC legal track), patent collections (CLEF-IP), medical collections (Pub-Med) etc.

**Availability:**

Most of these collections are freely available. You just need to register for the track (if it's an ongoing one) and they will make the data available to you. Some past tracks make the data available in the track web-pages.
The TREC ad hoc and the ClueWeb data are not freely available. The recent tracks of TREC make the data freely available, though. The various datasets of INEX, FIRE, and CLEF are all freely available. Just send an email to the (past) organizers in case they have removed the links to the data.